# Bind Application to Specific JBoss socket-binding

Tags: jboss

My goal is to have two different applications hosted on different ports via JBoss AS 7.x.  For example:

- app1 is accessible on https port 9443
- app2 is NOT accessible on https port 10443
- app2 is accessible on https port 10443
- app1 is NOT accessible on https port 10443

From what I understand, I will create two socket-bindings, "httpsApp1" and "httpsApp2".  Then create matching connectors with the ssl options of my choice.  What I am missing is how I tie app1 to and only to httpsApp1, and app2 to and only to httpsApp2.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

P.S. I am pretty new to JBoss, so if my my assumptions are wrong, please feel free to course correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do as you say, which is create those two socket bindings.

However, by doing so you need to run **two** JBoss AS 7.x instances since they'll bind to their correct socket binding then you deploy app1 to jboss1 and then app2 to jboss2.

That way app1 is only running under the lower port and app2 is only running under the higher port.

Comment: It seems odd that there isn't a deployment descriptor that can bind a deployment to a connector/socket-binding.  Thanks for the info though, I will take a look at running two instance.